Month and year input for bank card on React
I want to create the input string where a user can input an expire date of his bank card. I would like the values in the input string look like "MM/YY" and after pressing a key each of the subsquent values (M then M then Y and one more Y) changes to the key, that user pressed
I did try this code, but ran into difficulties with changing characters MM and YY
import React, { useState, useRef} from 'react';


function ExpireDate() {
    const [expireDate, setExpireDate] = useState([])

    const handleExpireDate = event => {
        const keyPressed = event.key

        if (!/\d/.test(keyPressed)) {
            if (keyPressed === 'Backspace') {
                setExpireDate((prev) => {
                    const newValue = [...prev]
                    newValue.pop()
                    
                    return newValue;
                })
            }

            return;
        
            
        }
        
        setExpireDate((prev) => {
            if (prev.length >=2) {
                return prev;
            }

            const newValue = [...prev]
            newValue.push(keyPressed)

            return newValue;
        })
    }


    const formattedExpireDate = (expireDate) => {
        console.log(`Expire date is: ${JSON.stringify(expireDate)}`)

        const month = new Array(2 - expireDate.length).fill('M').join('')
        const displayExpireDate = (expireDate.join('') + month)
            .replace(/(.{1,2})/, '$1/')
        

        return displayExpireDate;
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <br />
                <input 
                className={`expire-date`}
                value={formattedExpireDate(expireDate)}
                onChange={() => {}}
                onKeyDown={handleExpireDate}
                size='5'
                placeholder=''
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
} 


export default ExpireDate;


If you use two boxes for month and year you won't have to worry about formatting. Example of the kinds of problems you may face....

"but ran into difficulties" WHAT difficulties?

Warning:
Manipulating input field is generally a bad idea if not executed correctly. Think about cursor position, copy and paste, delete vs backspace, text selection, drag and drop etc. There are so many things to consider.
If you can help it, a basic placeholder with validation is good enough in most cases as oppose to fancy manipulation.

In the case the value shown in the input box being different from the actual input, you should store the actual input and the display value separately, and derive the display value from the actual input.
To derive your desired format from a 0-4 character string, you can

cut the string into 2 halves, the first half is month and the second half is year
append "MM" to month, then take the first 2 characters.
append "YY" to year, then take the first 2 characters.
join 2 halves with "/"

  const [expireDateInput, setExpireDateInput] = useState("");
  const expireDate = useMemo(() => {
    const mm = (expireDateInput.slice(0, 2) + "MM").slice(0, 2);
    const yy = (expireDateInput.slice(2) + "YY").slice(0, 2);
    return `${mm}/${yy}`;
  }, [expireDateInput]);

Now to handle keydown event
  const handleExpireDate: KeyboardEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> = (event) => {
    const keyPressed = event.key;
    if (keyPressed === "Backspace") {
      setExpireDateInput((prev) => prev.slice(0, -1));
    } else if (/^[0-9]$/.test(keyPressed)) {
      setExpireDateInput((prev) => (prev + keyPressed).slice(0, 4));
    }
  };

Note that the input is limited to 4 characters so that you won't be backspacing invisible characters if you have input more than 4 characters.
And to finish off
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        value={expireDate}
        onChange={() => {}}
        onKeyDown={handleExpireDate}
      ></input>
    </div>
  );

